# A sphere circumscribing a truncated rectangular pyramid

Tags: geometry

Assume I have a truncated rectangular pyramid with side length $a$, $b$ (large base area) and $c$, $d$ (smaller base area) and height $h$.

I would like to find the minimal sphere, which circumscribes this truncated pyramid. Am I correct, when I simply take the distance between the "bottom right far corner" and the "top left near" corner and the distance between those two is the diameter of such a sphere? (I only seek the volume of such a sphere, the position of its center is irrelevant to me).

Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Suppose you had a flat-ish pyramid with a smaller "top base" relative to the "base-base,"  Then the distance across the diagonal of the "base-base" would be longer than the distance from the top right corner to the bottom right corner.

Comment: calculate it based on the trapezoid inscribed in a large circle of the sphere.